# Compiling python from source error with shared library loading error

Tags: python, compiler-construction, shared-libraries

When I try to run python I get the error:

python2.6: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I had previously compiled python with no issues and ran it fine. I didn't enable --with-threads or --enable-shared. Now that I enabled these two compile options I get this error when trying to run it. The file libpython is in $HOME/lib and python is in $HOME/bin.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo ldconfig -n $HOME/lib`

ought to fix the problem. otherwise, `strace python` and pastebin the results.

Comment: Don't have access to sudo but yeah I immediately realized that it wasn't in the LD-LIBRARY_PATH after posting so just appended it and launches with no worries now. Is there a way as a compile option to force it to look in $HOME/lib for python libraries. That is really what I want to do. Also so when I run python setup.py it looks in lib for packages where I don't have to set the PYTHONPATH. I assume there should be a way to do this on compilation.

Comment: "make install" should have done that (run ldconfig) for you, surprised that it didn't.

Comment: what exactly do you mean "as a compile option"?

Comment: `-Wl,--rpath=$HOME/lib` will embed $HOME/lib into the python executable as an additional directory to look in when searching for shared libraries.  Figure out how to add that to the linker options.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx - I meant that if I put in the linker that I want to include that folder during compiling that Python will automatically look there. So LDDFLAGS=$HOME/lib or something like that. There is no ldconfig that I can run and I don't have root access to the system so wouldn't matter either way. The best I can do I think is just add an export statement in .bashrc.

Comment: OK, I guess you saw Michael Kent's comment too.

Comment: @Michael Kent - In make I assume that would be CPPFLAGS="-W1 --rpath=$HOME/lib" or does it also need to be set in LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/lib". Not that fluent with make system. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Figured it out here: http://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/notes/rpath.html. Need to add LDFLAGS="-R $HOME/lib". Thanks for the help and give this a go now to let you know how it goes.

Comment: It would be in LDFLAGS, and it's `-Wl,-rpath=$HOME/lib`.  That's the letter 'l', not numeral '1', after the '-W', no space after the comma, and a single dash before 'rpath' (I mistakenly typed two dashes in my previous comment).